# WP7 - Size of forward navigation?

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Lets say i have 2 pages A and B. I navigate from A to B. B has no references to A. Then is A up for garbage collection? What will happen if i press the back button? Will page A be created again? Or is the previous page A loaded from cache, if so then is it loaded in the same state i left it in or from some default init state?

If previous pages are cached then how long a forward navigation can i do being sure that the first page will not be removed from the stack.

If the previous pages are cached then can they be changed or updated from a different page which had a reference to them?

Answer (score 0):

Pages are kept in memory until such time as they are backed out of.

Istvan Cerri demonstrated memeory handling wrt page navigation at Mix. You can see it in the video of his talk around 24 minutes in.

Comment: No worries, let us know how it went.